# Add text to WooCommerce Loop Category Count

Tags: woocommerce

I was wondering if anyone might know how to add text to the 'count function' in the Woocommerce Category Loop.
At present under each category thumbnail it shows the name of the category and in brackets the number of products in that category.
What I would like to be able to do is to add a word after the Count.
We are a non profit which provides free educational lessons.
And I would like to add the word lessons after the count.
So it would show the Category title and then - for example (3 lessons)

Any suggestions welcomed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the hook `woocommerce_subcategory_count_html`. You can find the documentation here:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_template_loop_category_title.html#1105-1122

<strike>I haven't tested it, but you'll need to do something like this.</strike> Now it works.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', 'myFunction', 10, 2);
function myFunction($html, $category){
    return ' <mark class="count">(' . esc_html( $category->count ) . ' lessons)</mark>';
}
```

Good luck! Let me know it it worked.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying.
Am a bit of a novice at this level!
I just got this error...
"Use of undefined constant myFunction - assumed 'myFunction' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"

Comment: Whoops. There should be `'` around the function name. I've updated it. Without these the interpreter thinks that it's a constant created by the `define` function.

Comment: Hi
Just one other question on this subject. Is it possible to remove the name of the category in the loop and just show the lessons count?
I can't find anywhere the file which contains the whole loop!

Comment: Than you'll need to unhook `woocommerce_template_loop_category_title`, rewrite it without the title and add this new hook. But that's more work and an entirely different question.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do the same for the product category count list in the sidebar when working with WooCommerce? I actually wish to remove the brackets and style the count number.